# unique_copy for a class does not recognize the operator<

Tags: c++, stl

I can't understand what the compiler error message means about unique_copy:

> error C2672:  'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded
>   function found

```
std::unique_copy(begin(collection_raw), end(collection_raw), back_inserter(collection_sorted));
```

I submit collections of employee with the less operator, like this:

```
struct employee
{
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
};

// Employees comparer
bool operator<(const employee& item1, const employee& item2)
{
    return item1.name < item2.name;
}
```

The error message comes from Visual Studio 2019 and I am not sure what it means.

Below a sample that compiles because I commented-out std::unique_copy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

struct employee
{
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
};

// Employee comparer
bool operator<(const employee& item1, const employee& item2)
{
    return item1.name < item2.name;
}

// Copy the raw vector of employees into a list of sorted and unique employees
void copy_uniq_elements(std::vector<employee>& collection_raw, std::list<employee>& collection_sorted)
{
    // use operator< to order items
    std::sort(begin(collection_raw), end(collection_raw));

    // Don't copy adjacent equal elements
    // error C2672:  'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found
    // std::unique_copy(begin(collection_raw), end(collection_raw), back_inserter(collection_sorted));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<employee> staff { {"Bob", "11 rue de longueil"},
                                  {"Arnold", "22 rue de la retraite"},
                                  {"Gilbert", "33 rue de belle-humeur"},
                                  {"Xavier", "11 rue de longueil"} };

    std::list<employee> staff_sorted;
    copy_uniq_elements(staff, staff_sorted);

    for (const auto item : staff_sorted)
    {
        std::cout << item.name << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I personally would rather accept the vector by value (so you create a copy immediately), sort it, then apply [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) to it (don't forget the erase!) and finally return the result. This way, you wouldn't need to modify the input vector (but you'd get a vector instead of a list – any reason for preferring the latter?).

Comment: Alternatively, you could apply `std:unique` directly to the input vector, then it would be up to the user to decide if she/he want's to copy or not (well, you'd need to rename the function then...).

Comment: I tried following your advice but got the same error: std::list<employee> copy_uniq_elements2(std::vector<employee> collection_raw)
{
    std::list<employee> collection_sorted{};

    // use operator< to order items
    std::sort(begin(collection_raw), end(collection_raw));

    // Don't copy adjacent equal elements
    // error C2672:  'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found
    std::unique_copy(begin(collection_raw), end(collection_raw), back_inserter(collection_sorted));

    return collection_sorted;
}

Comment: `operator<` is needed for sorting, unifying requires `opperator==`. GCC error message is more precise about: `/usr/include/c++/8/bits/predefined_ops.h:106:23: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘employee’ and ‘employee’)` That applies for both `std::unique` and `std::unique_copy`.

Comment: Thanks, you got it! It works now when I add bool operator==(const employee& item1, const employee& item2)
{
    return item1.name == item2.name;
}

Comment: Now I understand: the operator< was only for sort while std::unique_copy uses operator==

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overload the `== operator` for the Employee.

```
bool operator==(const employee& item1, const employee& item2)
{
    // something.
}
```

or pass a Binary predicate to the std::unique_copy

```
std::unique_copy(begin(collection_raw), end(collection_raw), back_inserter(collection_sorted), 
         [] (auto& b, auto& c) { return b.name == c.name; } );
```